# Regex string until unescaped comma

Tags: php, regex

I have the following string:

```
{lorum=Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere\, consectetur est at lobortis.,ipsum= Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.}
```

Now, what I want to get is:

```
array (
    array( 
        'operator' => 'lorum',
        'value' => 'Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Sed posuere\, consectetur est at lobortis.'
    ),
    array(
        'operator' => 'ipsum',
        'value' => 'Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.'
    )
)
```

The biggest problem is that I can't get my regex to do a lookbehind on a `.*`, I was trying something like this (without naming the groups yet btw).

```
[{,]?([a-zA-Z_]*)=((?<!\\).*)[(?<!\\),}]
```

I'm using the [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) engine from Gskinner to try out my regex's , also I tried a lot of other variations, but non successful till now...

Eventually this regex should be used in a PHP script. Ofcourse, I would not mind to totally rebuild the above regex, though I would like to keep it on a regex level. If not for the sake of speed, then just for regex educational purposes.

Comment: I believe `.*` is greedy, which would cause you to not be able to look behind it.

Comment: I was having the idea that that was the problem. Is there any other regex way to get the above results?

Comment: quantifiers are not allowed in php lookbehinds, only .net does support unlimited length lookbehinds.

Comment: Have you considered using preg_split? You can split on a comma not preceded by a backslash, and then process those individual strings to get key and value. Not a one-regex solution, but should work.

Comment: Why should your output contain ` a pharetra augue.`? It's after an unescaped comma. Did you mean to escape that comma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stema said in a comment, lookbehinds have to be of fixed length (or at least of finite length) in all regex engines except .NET's. Also `[(?<!\\),}]` doesn't mean anything really. It just matches any of the characters inside the square brackets. You could reverse your attempt and consume anything except for commas that are not escaped and closing braces:

```
([a-zA-Z_]*)=((?:[^\\,}]|\\.)*)
```

In free-spacing mode with some explanation:

```
([a-zA-Z_]*)=    # match and capture the key (as in your own regex)
(                # capture the value
  (?:            # non-capturing group for allowed sequences for the value
    [^\\,}]      # any character except backslash, comma and closing brace
  |              # OR
    \\.          # a backslash followed by anything
  )
  *              # repeat as long as possible
)                # end of capturing group
```

Note that this allows escaping of any character (including other backslashes and closing braces).

Note that PHP's `preg_match_all` will return the array in a slightly different structure than you need it (but it's easy to shift around to your needs). Also, in a PHP string you won't get around double escaping all the backslashes, so you'll have four of them each time. Like:

```
$pattern = '/([a-zA-Z_]*)=((?:[^\\\\,}]|\\\\.)*)/';
```

[Working demo.](http://ideone.com/0MSV2g)

Also note that greedy patterns that cannot go past the end of what you want to match are in most cases more efficient than non-greedy solutions that try to find the first thing that is disallowed.

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thanks a lot! Could you possibly clarify the workflow of that regex by multilining that? Marking as answer!

Comment: Yeah! When I refreshed the page, it magically appeared. ;) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The .* is being greedy and preventing the match.  Try

`[{,]?([a-zA-Z_]*?)=((?<!\\).*?)[(?<!\\),}]`

Rubular: http://rubular.com/r/l8R3GCmalw

Comment: I think this would exclude the last part of the value from the escaped comma down the road. I think this flaw originates from my original regex, which would be authored by me. Though, I'm not really sure why this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:  http://rubular.com/r/XLI9euNcL5

`[{,]?([a-zA-Z_]*?)=(.*?)(?:[^\\][,]|})`